# Maximal and Prime Ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Consider a field $K$. I have seen that the ideal $(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$ is a prime ideal in $K[X,Y,Z]$. But now I have to see that it is not a maximal ideal. Therefore, I have to find an ideal between $(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$ and $K[X,Y,Z]$. Could $(X,Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$ be the maximal ideal I am looking for?

Comment: Or you can prove that $K[X,Y,Z]/(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$ is not a field.

Comment: Note that $Y$ and $Z$ are also in the ideal $I=(X,Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$, then $K[X,Y,Z]/I$ is isomorphic to $K$.

Comment: @fernanfio $K$[$X,Y,Z$]$/I$ is isomorphic to $K$ or to $K[X]$??

Comment: Is isomorphic to $K$; the homomorphism $\psi:K[X,Y,Z]\rightarrow K$ defined by $\psi(p)=p(0,0,0)$ has $I$ as kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(X,Y-X^2,Z-X^3)=(X,Y,Z)$, and thus the factor ring is isomorphic to $K$ as you were already told in the comments.

Comment: So is it a maximal ideal? Or $(X,Y-X^2,Z-X^3)=K[X,Y,Z]$?

Comment: @Blanca If $(X,Y,Z)=K[X,Y,Z]$ then $1\in (X,Y,Z)$, and therefore $1=Xf+Yg+Zh$. Now sent $X,Y,Z$ to zero and find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(X,Y-X^2,Z-X^3)=(X,Y,Z)$ and because $(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)\subset (X,Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$, hence $ (Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$ not maximal ideal.